# Pop-Up a menu on Google Map with two buttons

Tags: android, popup, maps

i want to pop up a menu on touching the map, the menu should have two buttons 1. SetAs-Source 2. SetAsDestination. ! on clicking the source the point should be stored in a GeoPoint Variable and the button should then we disabled after setting as source, also i would like to add a image at that point.

I am able to add a Item in The Itemizedoverlay and show a pushpin over there, but before doing this all i want to popup a menu pointing over the touched(like traditionaly google pop-up ) and on setting as source, it should add the item .

The popup should be like as you see in the image but, instead of plain text i want to add buttons

Thanks In Advance ! 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for like this ??

[image]

Then use Android MapView Balloons. Its pretty easy to use. Just find out more [Here](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons/tree/master/android-mapviewballoons-example)

Hope this helps !

Comment: does it provide button facility too ?

Comment: how to use? where i get the library ?

Comment: Why you need a button on the overlay? To do some on-click actions right? So this balloon pop up will work for you. Check this https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons   Download the projects zip file. On extract you will find two projects. Import both two projects to your Eclipse . Now run the Example. That's it